# Image changed randomly in table view cell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I want to change a specific `UIImageView` inside a `UITableViewCell` with this:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    UYLTextCell *textCell = (UYLTextCell *)cell;
    textCell.selected = YES;
    //get and show the image at selected cell
    textCell.testImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image280280.jpg"];
    //[tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

But what happened is some cell had their image View even though it has not been clicked.

Comment: can you post your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Table views re-use cells. When a cell is scrolled offscreen it is added to a queue, and will be re-used for the next cell to be scrolled onscreen. That means your cell configuration code in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` should be enough to properly configure any cell, including cells that were previously selected at a different indexPath. In `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` store the selected index path in a property and use that property to configure your cell in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`. The image will need to be set in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` whether the cell is selected or not (unless you implement `prepareForReuse` in your custom cell).

Comment: You don't need to reload the whole table - that will cause flickering. It is ok to change the image in `didSelectRowAtindexPath` as long as `cellForRowAtIndexPath` returns a non-nil value (which it will since the row was just selected). Chances are good that the OP isn't correctly resetting the cell state in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` however

Comment: Agreed, though I prefer the configuration code to be in one place. I updated my answer anyway.

Comment: You can have another method that configures the cell which you call from `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and, say, `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` but it is very inefficient to reload an entire tableview just to update one cell

Comment: Yes I would normally use `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` but sometimes it's easier not to complicate an answer. Having another method that configures the cell would work well.